# Instagram Basic why need to include manage_pages to submit for review?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

We have updated our application to new Instagram API platform, we only use Instagram basic display API
(instagram_graph_user_profile and instagram_graph_user_media).

Why the `manage_pages` required in order to submit the application? We are only using Instagram basic display API and does not require to manage the Facebook page.
[image]

Comment: This is not about the Basic Display API, but the `instagram_basic` permission. That is for managing IG _business_ accounts, and those need to be connected to a Facebook page. If you are not using that feature, and added this item to your review submission yourself - then remove it again.

Comment: @CBroe, I only need to use the basic display API, but in order to approve my application do I need to integrate the feature of instagram_basic like Facebook Login and  IG business accounts?

Comment: Don’t confuse the Facebook API `instagram_basic` _permission_, with the Instagram Basic _API_. Despite the rather unlucky naming conflict, those are two different things. You only need `instagram_basic`, if you want to work with _business/creator_ accounts, using the Instagram Graph API. If you want to work with the Instagram Basic Display API, then `instagram_basic` doesn’t even come into play.

Comment: Thank you @CBroe really helpful !!!